# Are there anydice function(s) or code for Savage Worlds rolls?

Tags: savage-worlds, anydice

I am trying to use the exploding function and the highest of functions, but I am having issues with the skill die or wild die side of the roll.

If I do 
output [highest 1 of 1d4 + 1d6] 
I get a minimum result of 2...which tells me I am doing this wrong.  Is there a way to do highest of d4 OR d6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax for non-exploding and taking highest is:

```
output [highest of d4 and d6]
```

For [exploding](http://anydice.com/articles/exploding-dice/), simply add the `[explode <roll>]` tag, so the result will be something like:

```
output [highest of [explode d4] and [explode d6]]
```

Comment: I see so I should be ok with this.
output [highest of 1@[explode d4] and 1@[explode d6]]

Comment: There are some edge cases in Savage Worlds where dice do not explode, most notably damage to inanimate objects like busting down a door. So thanks for including both!

Comment: Also note a roll of 1 on a sorcery-based spell-casting roll results in backlash regardless of the roll on the Wild die.

Comment: I think that last one has too many highest of and could just be `output [highest of [explode 1d4] and [explode 1d6]]`. Not confident enough with anydice to just edit the answer though...

Comment: @Chris you are correct that they wield the same result. Back when I wrote this answer, I had some kind of issue with *highest of* that forced me to input a number (highest 1 of) and led me to this code. But *explode* already wields the highest result.

Comment: I was bold and edited your answer to simplify it. I'm confident that at least nowadays the extra `1@` and `[highest 1 of ...]` wrappers [do nothing](https://anydice.com/program/214ac) when applied to single dice. (I cannot completely rule out the possibility that they might have been needed in the past due to bugs in older versions of AnyDice.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Nope, they werent needed. Its just a coding practice of mine to always spell the obvious, because even if its obvious to experts, it might not be to beginners. So that "1" there makes it obvious you can get more than one "highest" by adding a number in front of it.

Answer (score -2):

I think I worked it out.

function: reroll R:n under N:n {
if R < N { result: [highest of [explode 1d6] and [explode 1d6]] } else {result: R}
}

output [reroll [highest of [explode 1d6] and [explode 1d6]] under 4]
output [highest of [explode 1d6] and [explode 1d6]]

Comment: Is this supposed to be a self-answer to your [own question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/182264/52137)? We're Ok with those if they work, but obviously it needs to be in the right place :)

Comment: Also, this answer doesn't appear to be quite correct, since AFAIK rerolling using bennies in Savage Worlds lets you keep the original result if you roll lower on the reroll, whereas your function always returns the rerolled value if it rerolls at all. Of course, if you only reroll when your original roll would fail, then this doesn't really matter much.